# D3 mercator function NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mercator

I'm not too familiar with the D3 mercator projection function, and I'm getting some unexpected results. I'd like to project the following latitude and longitude (somewhere in Mexico):

```
var geo = [19, -99]
```

I define my mercator projection using d3

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
projection(geo)
> [529.7418836818384, NaN]
```

which is a point obviously not on a map. What exactly am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Javascript has it's lat and long round the opposite way to the rest of the world, so what you've given D3 is a longditue of 19 and a latitude of -99.  Obviously there is no latitude of -99 hence the NaN.  Now if you just reverse your geo variable to

```
var geo = [-99, 19]
```

all should be good.