# Updated: changing the graph based on the slider date on x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

**Edit:** I have edited the question, earlier values were not reflecting on the x axis now that got resolved .Now as the slider moves the data doesn't change in the graph and i can see changing x values.

I'm trying to implement a jquery slider in d3 following this [link](http://bl.ocks.org/pranitar/01305d9ad0eba73dbf80). The example is generating data of some random numbers while my data is in the below format:

```
{storeid: 5722646637445120, peoplesum: 87, date: "2018-06-03"}
{storeid: 5722646637445120, peoplesum: 90, date: "2018-06-04"}
{storeid: 5722646637445120, peoplesum: 114, date: "2018-06-05"}
```

I'm able to trigger events when i move my slider but the values are not reflecting on the graph now. So that mean my view is not updating the SVG correctly which is my assumption. I could be wrong here as well.

My x axis should have the date range and y should be peoplesum  and it could be a single or a multiline graph.

Updated Code:

```
private initSvg() {
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    this.svg = d3.select("#d3Id")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
        .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
     .attr("stroke-width", 2);
  }
  private initAxis() {
    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = timeParse("%b %Y");
    this.formatTime = timeParse("%e %B");

    // Set the ranges
    this.x = d3Scale.scaleTime().range([0, this.width]);
    this.y = d3Scale.scaleLinear().range([this.height, 0]);
  }
  private drawAxis() {
      var X = this.x;
      var Y = this.y;
      this.xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.x)
          .ticks(5);

      // var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.x).tickSize(-this.height).ticks(3);
      // // Add the x-axis.
      // this.svg.append("svg:g")
      //       .attr("class", "x axis")
      //       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
      //       .call(xAxis);

      this.yAxis = d3.axisLeft(this.y)
          .ticks(5);
      // Define the line
      this.priceline = d3Shape.line()
          .x(function (d) { return X(new Date(d['date'])); })
          .y(function (d) { return Y(d['peoplesum']); });
  }
  private drawLine() {
    if ( this.data[0]['d3_parameter_maker'] === true)
      {
       this.x.domain([0, d3.max(this.data, function (d) { return d['date']; })]); 
      }
      else if ( this.data[0]['d3_parameter_maker'] === undefined)
      {
        //console.log("aksdad")
      var mindate = new Date(this.dashboard_date['startTime']),
          maxdate = new Date(this.dashboard_date['endTime']);
      this.x.domain([mindate,maxdate]);
      }

      console.log(new Date(this.dashboard_date['startTime']));

      // Scale the range of the data
      var svgVar = this.svg;
      var pricelineVar = this.priceline;
      var margin = this.margin;
      var height = this.height;
      let thisObj = this;
      this.mouseOver = [];
      let X = this.x;
      let Y = this.y;
      if ( this.mouseFlag < 0) {
        for ( let i = 0; i < this.peopleInSumArr.length; i++) {
            this.mouseOver[i] = true;
        }
      } else {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.peopleInSumArr.length; i++) {
              if (i !== this.mouseFlag) {
                this.mouseOver[i] = false;
              }
          }
          this.mouseOver[this.mouseFlag] = true;
      }
      this.y.domain([0, d3.max(this.data, function (d) { return d['peoplesum']; })]);
      // Nest the entries by symbol
      var dataNest = d3.nest()
          .key(function (d) { return d['storeid']; })
          .entries(this.data);
      // set the colour scale
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
      var legendSpace = this.width / dataNest.length; // spacing for the legend
      var div1 = d3.select("body").append("div")
          .attr("class", "tooltip")
          .style("opacity", 0);
      dataNest.forEach(function (data, i) {
          thisObj.svg.append("path")
              .attr("class", "line")
              .style("fill", "none")
              .attr("d", thisObj.priceline(data.values))
              .attr('opacity', thisObj.mouseOver !== undefined && thisObj.mouseOver[i] === true ? 1 : 0.2)
              .style('cursor', 'pointer')
              .style("stroke", function () { // Add the colours dynamically
                  return data['color'] = color(data.key);
              })
              .attr("stroke-width", 3)
              .on('click', function () { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
                  thisObj.mouseFlag = i;
                  thisObj.initSvg();
                  thisObj.initAxis();
                  thisObj.drawAxis();
                  thisObj.drawLine();
              });
          // Add the scatterplot
          thisObj.svg.selectAll("dot")
              .data(data.values)
              .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("r", 5)
              .attr("cx", function (d) { return thisObj.x(new Date(d.date)); })
              .attr("cy", function (d) { return thisObj.y(d.peoplesum); })
              .style('cursor', 'pointer')
              .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                  div1.transition()
                      .duration(200)
                      .style("opacity", .9);
                  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
                  div1.html("<b>Date: </b>" + d.date + "<br/>" + "<b>Sum: </b>" + d.peoplesum.toFixed(2))
                      .style('position', 'absolute')
                      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
                      .style('text-align', 'center')
                      .style('width', '100px')
                      .style('height', '30px')
                      .style('padding', '2px')
                      .style('font', '12px sans-serif')
                      .style('background-color', 'lightsteelblue')
                      .style('border', '0px')
                      .style('border-radius', '8px')
                      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
                      .style('pointer-events', 'none');
              })
              .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                  div1.transition()
                      .duration(500)
                      .style("opacity", 0);
              });

          // Add the X Axis


          // Add the Y Axis

          thisObj.svg.append("text")
              .attr("x", (legendSpace / 2) + i * legendSpace)  // space legend
              .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom / 2) + 5)
              .attr("class", "legend")    // style the legend
              .style('cursor', 'pointer')
              .style("fill", function () { // Add the colours dynamically
                  return data['color'] = color(data.key);
              })
              .text(data.key)
              .attr("stroke-width", 3)
              .on('click', function () { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
                  thisObj.mouseFlag = i;
                  thisObj.initSvg();
                  thisObj.initAxis();
                  thisObj.drawAxis();
                  thisObj.drawLine();
              });
      });
      // Add the X Axis
      let xAxisSelection= this.svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x-axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")

        xAxisSelection.call(d3.axisBottom(this.x));

      // Add the Y Axis

       let yAxisLeft =this.svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")

            yAxisLeft.call(d3.axisLeft(this.y));

       var clip = this.svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("id", "clip-rect")
        .attr("x", "0")
        .attr("y", "0")
        .attr("width", this.width)
        .attr("height", this.height);


      // Add the line by appending an svg:path element with the data line we created above
      // do this AFTER the axes above so that the line is above the tick-lines
      var path = this.svg.append("svg")
        .attr("class","path")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr( thisObj.priceline(this.data));



    function zoom(begin, end) {  
    thisObj.x.domain([begin, end - 1]);

    var t = thisObj.svg.transition().duration(0);

    var size = moment(moment(end).toDate()).diff(moment(begin).toDate(), 'days');
    console.log("size",size);
    var step = size / 10;
    var ticks = [];
    const startDate = new Date(moment(begin).toDate());
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {        
        var xAxisDate = new Date(moment(begin).toDate())
        // Add a day
        xAxisDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i)

        ticks.push(xAxisDate);
    }

    xAxisSelection.call(d3.axisBottom(thisObj.x.domain(d3.extent(ticks))));
  }

  //console.log("this.data)",this.data)
  $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
           min: new Date(mindate).getTime() / 1000,
      max: new Date(maxdate).getTime() / 1000,
      step: 86400,
             values: [ new Date(mindate).getTime() / 1000, new Date(maxdate).getTime() / 1000 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
              //console.log("ui.values[0]",ui.values)

              var begin = d3.min([(new Date(ui.values[ 0 ] *1000).toDateString() ), thisObj.data.length]);
              var end = new Date(ui.values[ 1 ] *1000).toDateString(); // 0]);
              //console.log("begin:", moment(begin).toDate(), "end:", moment(end).format('yyyy-mm-dd'), thisObj.data);
              console.log(begin);
              console.log(end);

              zoom(begin, end);
            }
        });
    });

    }
}
```

Please find below the screenshot of the graph
[image]

Comment: @Andrew Reid  any comments from you on this

Comment: I'm only kind of online at the moment - enjoying the longest day of the year here (the sun sets in an hour at 11:40pm) sitting on the patio - I'll be able to take a closer look tomorrow. But to clarify does either of your axis or line/path update when you move the slider?

Comment: @AndrewReid yes that is the problem it doesn't update when i move the slider

Comment: @AndrewReid  I have edited my question

Comment: Sorry for the delay - things were a bit busy yesterday. Is it possible to make a plunkr of the code or to share the code (say as a bl.ock/gist) as it is currently?

Comment: @AndrewReid i have used js fiddle to present the code in the best possible way with the link https://jsfiddle.net/neudc0fx/2/   . The code here doesn't show the silder part but if you will just run the code as simple  html in your browser you will be able to see the full graph and features. I tried my hands on bl.ock.org but can't see my gist block .

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavk1992/814207c96c6dc4c98c8e21d7585ae18c/raw/60ada2964894a390007f6ccfc61e50b8c9f4f554/line_chart.html   is the link and i'm facing some problem publishing my block. Please let me know if you need further inputs @AndrewReid

Comment: The nature of the problem is relatively straight-forward: you are rescaling the x axis but you aren't updating the line or the points (with an update selection). But we can't simply call `drawLine` because it will use a different domain, but it also doesn't use a standard update cycle. While the jQuery doesn't really complicate things too much in this instance, a common pure d3 way to accomplish the slider effect is using a brush (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172). I'll continue to look at the code here though.

Comment: The domain of the x axis has invalid dates - since you stringify the dates, we need to use new Date() when setting the new x domain. Then we can position the circles as we did originally by using .attr("cx"... .attr("cy")... on a selection `of d3.selectAll("circle")` (since there are no other circles). Unfortunately there is no bound data on the path, so we need to bind data there (two lines commented in the forEach loop - which is atypical for appending items in d3, partly because it makes data binding less friendly). The line updates similarily to the circles, d3.select(".line").attr("d"...)

Comment: [Here's](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/raw/ff1ae7bfdb23f2967b2dad2bfd98edd6/) a minimally changed example of the lower end of the slider working. One issue in the original and this, if you notice, if you slide the slider in one position and back to the end (on the left), the ticks do not move into their original position. So I'm a bit unsure on the tick method being accurate after many zooms. Another thing is you'll need is to clip the circles and line now that the graph updates - the scale will interpolate positions that are beyond the plot area.

Comment: (There also seems to be an issue with the logic pulling the dates in the original - carried forward by me, I don't think the domain is as intended).

Comment: @AndrewReid how can i see the code for this  http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/raw/ff1ae7bfdb23f2967b2dad2bfd98edd6/

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just used raw view to make the slider visible: http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/ff1ae7bfdb23f2967b2dad2bfd98edd6/  - I apologize on the spacing - I forget Git draws tabs differently than my editor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173732/discussion-between-codaholic-and-andrew-reid).

Comment: @AndrewReid earlier the data was moving beyond y axis so i added the clip path functionality. The code is working fine now. I'm posting my answer here if you want you can copy and paste as your answer and i will accept the answer. As you had put in efforts to solve it i don't want to take the credits from you or if you want a jsfiddle link i can post that as well. Your work is appreciated and will keep you posted any future help on d3

Comment: I didn't have much of an answer - just updated the line. Glad I could help - but I think you could add the updating the line portion to your answer (as it is fairly key to the text of the question)

Comment: yes i have this line in my code d3.selectAll(".line").attr("d", function(d) {
                return thisObj.priceline(d.values);
            })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the clip path functionality because data was going beyond y axis.

```
    private initSvg() {
        d3.select("svg").remove();
        this.svg = d3.select("#d3Id")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
            .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2);
    }
    private initAxis() {
        // Parse the date / time
        // var parseDate = timeParse("%b %Y");
        // this.formatTime = timeParse("%e %B");

        // Set the ranges
        this.x = d3Scale.scaleTime().range([0, this.width]);
        this.y = d3Scale.scaleLinear().range([this.height, 0]);
    }
    private drawAxis() {
        var X = this.x;
        var Y = this.y;
        this.xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.x)
            .ticks(5);

        // var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.x).tickSize(-this.height).ticks(3);
        // // Add the x-axis.
        // this.svg.append("svg:g")
        //       .attr("class", "x axis")
        //       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
        //       .call(xAxis);

        this.yAxis = d3.axisLeft(this.y)
            .ticks(5);
        // Define the line
        this.priceline = d3Shape.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return X(new Date(d['date']));
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return Y(d['peoplesum']);
            });
    }
    private drawLine() {

        if (this.data[0]['d3_parameter_maker'] === true) {
            this.x.domain([1, d3.max(this.data, function(d) {
                return parseInt(d['date']);
            })]);
        } else if (this.data[0]['d3_parameter_maker'] === undefined) {
            var mindate = new Date(this.dashboard_date['startTime']),
                maxdate = new Date(this.dashboard_date['endTime']);
            this.x.domain([mindate, maxdate]);
        }

        console.log(new Date(this.dashboard_date['startTime']));

        // Scale the range of the data
        var svgVar = this.svg;
        var pricelineVar = this.priceline;
        var margin = this.margin;
        var height = this.height;
        let thisObj = this;
        this.mouseOver = [];
        let X = this.x;
        let Y = this.y;
        if (this.mouseFlag < 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.peopleInSumArr.length; i++) {
                this.mouseOver[i] = true;
            }
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.peopleInSumArr.length; i++) {
                if (i !== this.mouseFlag) {
                    this.mouseOver[i] = false;
                }
            }
            this.mouseOver[this.mouseFlag] = true;
        }
        this.y.domain([0, d3.max(this.data, function(d) {
            return d['peoplesum'];
        })]);

        var clip = thisObj.svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("id", "clip-rect")
            .attr("x", "0")
            .attr("y", "0")
            .attr("width", this.width)
            .attr("height", this.height);
        // Nest the entries by symbol
        var dataNest = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {
                return d['storeid'];
            })
            .entries(this.data);
        // set the colour scale
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
        var legendSpace = this.width / dataNest.length; // spacing for the legend
        var div1 = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);
        dataNest.forEach(function(data, i) {
            thisObj.svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .style("fill", "none")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    return thisObj.priceline(d.values);
                })
                .attr('opacity', thisObj.mouseOver !== undefined && thisObj.mouseOver[i] === true ? 1 : 0.2)
                .style('cursor', 'pointer')
                .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                    return data['color'] = color(data.key);
                })
                .attr("stroke-width", 3)
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
                .on('click', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
                    thisObj.mouseFlag = i;
                    thisObj.initSvg();
                    thisObj.initAxis();
                    thisObj.drawAxis();
                    thisObj.drawLine();
                });
            // Add the scatterplot
            thisObj.svg.selectAll("dot")
                .data(data.values)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("r", 5)
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return thisObj.x(new Date(d.date));
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return thisObj.y(d.peoplesum);
                })
                .style('cursor', 'pointer')
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                    div1.transition()
                        .duration(200)
                        .style("opacity", .9);
                    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
                    div1.html("<b>Date: </b>" + d.date + "<br/>" + "<b>Sum: </b>" + d.peoplesum.toFixed(2))
                        .style('position', 'absolute')
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
                        .style('text-align', 'center')
                        .style('width', '100px')
                        .style('height', '30px')
                        .style('padding', '2px')
                        .style('font', '12px sans-serif')
                        .style('background-color', 'lightsteelblue')
                        .style('border', '0px')
                        .style('border-radius', '8px')
                        .style('cursor', 'pointer')
                        .style('pointer-events', 'none');
                })
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                    div1.transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .style("opacity", 0);
                });

            // Add the X Axis


            // Add the Y Axis

            thisObj.svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", (legendSpace / 2) + i * legendSpace) // space legend
                .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom / 2) + 5)
                .attr("class", "legend") // style the legend
                .style('cursor', 'pointer')
                .style("fill", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                    return data['color'] = color(data.key);
                })
                .text(data.key)
                .attr("stroke-width", 3)
                .on('click', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
                    thisObj.mouseFlag = i;
                    thisObj.initSvg();
                    thisObj.initAxis();
                    thisObj.drawAxis();
                    thisObj.drawLine();
                });
        });
        // Add the X Axis
        let xAxisSelection = this.svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x-axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")

        xAxisSelection.call(d3.axisBottom(this.x));

        // Add the Y Axis
        this.svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(this.y));
        if (this.data[0]['d3_parameter_maker'] === undefined) 
        {
          this.daily_Data_slider(mindate,xAxisSelection,maxdate)    
        }
       else 
        {
          this.hourly_Data_slider(xAxisSelection)    
        }
   }

  private daily_Data_slider(mindate,xAxisSelection,maxdate){
    var svgVar = this.svg;
        var pricelineVar = this.priceline;
        var margin = this.margin;
        var height = this.height;
        let thisObj = this;
    function zoom(begin, end) {

            thisObj.x.domain([new Date(begin), new Date(end)]);
            var t = thisObj.svg.transition().duration(0);

            var size = moment(moment(end).toDate()).diff(moment(begin).toDate(), 'days');
            console.log("size", size);
            var step = size / 10;
            var ticks = [];
            const startDate = new Date(moment(begin).toDate());
            for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                var xAxisDate = new Date(moment(begin).toDate())
                // Add a day
                xAxisDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i)

                ticks.push(xAxisDate);
            }

            xAxisSelection.call(d3.axisBottom(thisObj.x.domain(d3.extent(ticks))));
            // Redraw the line:    
            d3.selectAll("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return thisObj.x(new Date(d.date));
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return thisObj.y(d.peoplesum);
                })

            d3.selectAll(".line").attr("d", function(d) {
                return thisObj.priceline(d.values);
            })
        }

        //console.log("this.data)",this.data)
        $(function() {
            $("#slider-range").slider({
                range: true,
                min: new Date(mindate).getTime() / 1000,
                max: new Date(maxdate).getTime() / 1000,
                step: 86400,
                values: [new Date(mindate).getTime() / 1000, new Date(maxdate).getTime() / 1000],
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                    //console.log("ui.values[0]",ui.values)

                    var begin = d3.min([(new Date(ui.values[0] * 1000).toDateString()), thisObj.data.length]);
                    var end = new Date(ui.values[1] * 1000).toDateString(); // 0]);
                    //console.log("begin:", moment(begin).toDate(), "end:", moment(end).format('yyyy-mm-dd'), thisObj.data);
                    console.log("begin", begin);
                    console.log("end", end);

                    if (new Date(moment(moment(moment(begin).toDate()).add(10, 'days')).format("YYYY-MM-DD")) <= new Date(end)) {
                        zoom(begin, end);
                    }

                }
            });
        });
  }
```